# IE userData behavior doesn't work in IE for Windows Phone 7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7

I can't get the userData behavior to work in IE on WP7. *(Note: this refers to the original IE7 version of IE in WP7; not the IE9 version that will come with the Mango update.)* Does anyone know if this is a bug, or if the behavior just isn't implemented or enabled in the first place? Even better would be a workaround... I haven't found one yet.

Minimal test case:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #store {
                behavior:url('#default#userData');
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="store"></div>
        <h1>IE userData behavior test
        <script>
            var storageElement = document.getElementById("store");
            storageElement.setAttribute('monkey', 'fez');
            try {
                storageElement.save('storagetest');
                alert('Saved some data with the storage Element!'); // IE 7,8,9
            } catch(e) {
                alert("Failed to save data with the storage Element."); // IE on WP7
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(http://jsbin.com/urepoq/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was to try the `-ms-` prefix, as in `-ms-behavior`.  However, I'm fairly sure the IE7/IE8 hybrid browser on Windows Phone 7 doesn't support any behaviors whatsoever.  I'm unable to find solid confirmation on this, other than the few that I've tried that didn't work and the knowledge that VML (also implemented as behavior) isn't supported at all.

---

As the OP discovered, the very last section of [*Designing Web Sites for Mobile Phones*](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/Designing_Web_Sites_for_Phone_Browsers) states the following:

> ### Unsupported Plugins
>
> Unlike the desktop browser, Internet Explorer Mobile does not allow end users to download or install third-party plugins such as ActiveX controls. Web pages should not prompt users to download plugins. **Additionally Internet Explorer Mobile does not support DHTML or binary behaviors.**

So, it looks like you're out of luck.

Comment: It's kind of annoying that information about IE on WP7 is so hard to come by. I hope MS is going to bump the available support info when IE9/WP7 lands.

Comment: @Martin: at least then you'll probably be able to use `localStorage`.

Comment: IE Mobile for WP7 does not support HTML5 localStorage.

Comment: The _very last sentence_ of the document "Designing Web Sites for Phone Browsers" by the IE team (PDF link here: [link](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/Designing_Web_Sites_for_Phone_Browsers)) says: "Additionally Internet Explorer Mobile does not support DHTML or binary behaviors." This seems pretty definitive. Nuts.

Comment: @Martin: I meant that [IE9 on WP7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile#Internet_Explorer_Mobile_9) should support `localStorage`, I wasn't referring to the current browser.  I'll add your definitive quote to my answer to make that equally as definitive :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know that IE9 will; unfortunately IE7 on WP7 is the only game in time right now. (Unless you're one of the furtunates to have access to the Mango beta.) I'll update my question to make it clearer that it's asking about WP7 specifically. :-)